Cant populating existing datatable es6+
Link to test case:
https://codepen.io/arcanisgk-the-sasster/pen/ZYzJqwG
static async updateTable(info) {

        console.log("DatatablePlugin.updateTable");
        
        const table = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(`${info.target}`);
        console.log({'table':table});

        table.clear();

        console.log({'info.content.data':info.content.data});
        table.rows.add(info.content.data);

        table.draw();
        table.columns.adjust();

    }

Code snippets not supported by Staged are not supported. I have used Codepen... to show a working example with issues...
Error messages shown:
DataTables warning: table id=translations-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/4
Description of problem:
Hi, I'm back to my last stage of development related to datatables, in this case, as I do it in the test case, I'm trying to populate an existing datatable from a single script or method, that's why you can see that I'm trying to populate the table from a single static call to initialization and I'm not implementing Ajax.
In this case the problem has to do with the message, I am trying to clean the table in case it has previous data, and then I am trying to add new data, as well as make column adjustments if necessary... the problem is that the rows are added, but they do not have any data. As you can see I have created a Json/object structure that simulates the data.
The only thing I can think of is that I need to define the columns, in the initialization, so that in the update, you recognize where each piece of data should go... but I simply don't understand the error that appears... assuming that my json/object structure is correct.
I have tried to change the "updateTable" script

clone the current configuration.
destroy the table.
initialize it with the cloned data and configuration.

and with this new version i try the error disappears, but:

the configuration is not maintained
nor is the data displayed

updated code:
https://codepen.io/arcanisgk-the-sasster/pen/QwLMJdw
static async updateTable(info) {

        console.log("DatatablePlugin.updateTable");
        const jsonContent = typeof info.content.data === 'string' ? JSON.parse(info.content.data) : info.content.data;

        const target = $(`${info.target}`);
        const table = target.DataTable();
        const currentConfig = table.init();

        table.destroy();

        return target.DataTable({
            ...currentConfig.oInit,
            data: jsonContent.data
        });

    }

The existing post does not work in my implementation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62281831/28825980
how to pass array data to existing jquery datatable
